# Entity Framework Overwriting ID Values

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql, entity-framework

I am running into the same exact problem as asked in this question: [Entity Framework, Foreign Keys, and EntityKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648907/entity-framework-foreign-keys-and-entitykeys) where my Foreign ID key values are being reverted back to 0 before I am able to send the information to the database. This results in the error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with
>   the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Selection_Type".
>   The conflict occurred in database
>   "GenericDB", table
>   "dbo.Type", column
>   'TypeID'.

Unlike the poster of that question, I do not have the option to just use a primitive identifier. (The Selection table currently has two foreign keys as its primary key - GenericID + TypeID.) I know what is happening and why it's not working from a shallow level, but I cannot figure out why the ID values are not staying set to what I set them to and are, instead, reverting to 0 after the user POSTs their data selections.

Can anyone help clear this up a bit? It's making me nuts. (Everything else has worked so far with the Entity Framework.) Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a long shot...

But I wonder if you are running into the overlapping foreign keys problem outlined [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/11/01/tip-39-how-to-set-overlapping-fks-ef-4-0-only.aspx)?

The blog post includes the solution.